# Database design: Likes table

Tags: database, database-design, data-warehouse, database-normalization

I got two tables (for now):

1. `Topic`
2. `Post` (post is a comment for a topic)

I want to add the option to **Like** those objects.
so I thought about creating one table of Likes and using enum to indicate which object was liked (including the object's id of course).

by the way, if I choose this option, should it be an enum or another table represent all the objects:

> id     object_name
>   1      Topic
>   2      Post

another option is to create likes table for every object .

what is the best practice to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating a separate table for each object is better.

I don't see what you gain if you use only one table. You can't use foreign keys properly also in one table.

I mean you can't add a column `object_id` to your table, because you do not know the table to which it will point to. In this case you have two add two columns, `topic_id` and `post_id`. Always one of the two will be `NULL`.

Comment: but I can have an enum represents all the objects or use an `objects_table` for this cause

Comment: @socksocket Don't use `enum` for normalization.

Comment: @njk so using objects_table is ok?

Comment: @socksocket I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another table for the likes:

> tbl_posts_likes (likeID, userID, postID, like = 1, unlike = -1)

then you could write a subquery like:

```
SELECT SUM(like) as likeCount, SUM(unlike)
FROM tbl_posts_likes
GROUP BY postID
WHERE postID= posts.postID
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *how* you are tracking 'likes', I would recommend adding another table called `likes` to the following effect:

```
likes (like_id, like_type)
```

From this point, you would simply `COUNT()` the number of 'likes' for each `like_type` (topic/post) as each time someone likes either a topic or a post, a record would be inserted. However, if you plan to track 'likes' by user, you would need to add another column for user.

If you wanted to track the individual posts or topics, you would set up a table for each object and create a foreign key contraint for the topic or post `ID`.

```
topic_likes (tl_id, topic_id)
post_likes (pl_id, post_id)
```

The design above would create an entry for each like. If you are only concerned with the total number of likes for each object, you could set up something like so:

```
likes (like_id, like_type, likes)
```

Comment: Yes, but you can't track the like object(you can't use foreign key).

Comment: Going off OP's generic requirement to like the 'objects'.

Comment: Well, yeah. If he doesn't care about the concrete topic or post, then your solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

A table for likes is a overkill. When does anyone need to check who liked who's post. Very rarely. Its better to just maintain a count of likes and unlikes in the post table, and maintain a likes table only for archive and audit purpose. Basically for all regular operations use the counts, for audit needs.

This will prevent doing joins to calculate # of likes. Frankly accuracy of likes and unlikes is not that crucial. 99% accuracy is good enough. And consistency between API calls may cause a issue, that is very rare. Only on high load.

I also find doing operations like `SUM` on a database server is very costly. `JOIN` and then `SUM`, too painful and time consuming. Instead move the operation to the **compute**. On the API do the `++` or `--`. That will take the load off the DB for useless operations like this.